# How to retrieve nodes based on an integer within a string using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, linq-to-xml

This is my XML document:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para1</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading2" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para2</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading3" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para3</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading4" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para4</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para5</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading3" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para6</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading4" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para7</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading2" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para8</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <!-- This is my Current Node -->
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading3" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para9</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para10</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

So, while reading each element, I want to check the attribute `w:val` of `w:ppr/w:pstyle`. For example, in the above file, the first `w:p` contains that (`w:ppr/w:pstyle/@w:val`) attribute value as `Heading1`. So, For the first `w:p`, i don't care about anything and just take it. After, taken this `w:p`:

1. I want to split the attribute value `Heading1` for retrieving strings after the Heading. So, Now we get `1`. Afterwards, while reading the next `w:p`, apply the same logic for splitting the current attribute value. So, in this case, we have `2`. Now, I want to compare this current value `2` with previous value `1`.
2. If it is less than the previous value then only select the current `w:p`. Otherwise, don't do anything.

Apply the above step 1 and 2 for all of the `w:p` nodes. So, In my case, I want to select, only the following `w:p` nodes.

**Sample output nodes are (getting whole w:p node completely):**

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para1</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para5</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading2" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para8</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:ppr>
                <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1" />
            </w:ppr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Para10</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: If you want help with using XSLT or XSLT 2.0 then consider to explain what kind of output you want (i.e. plain text or XML or HTML or XHTML) and to show the result sample you want to create for your posted input sample.

Comment: @@Martin Honnen:Thanks a lot.Please See my updated Question...

Comment: I can't match your description of what you want with your example output. Is the example output wrong or have you not described this correctly? From what I understand, you want all `w:p` elements that "belong" to a header that is `n+1` level above the "current" node. Is that a correct understanding? Please adjust your language and/or example output to better explain what it is you want.

Comment: @asbjornu:I want to bring the nodes if current <w:p>'s w:val attribute value is less than to previous one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are saying is that you wish to ignore **w:p** nodes when the relevant **w:val** attribute is greater than the **w:val** element of the previous **w:p** (where it exists).

In XPath terms, where...

```
number(substring-after(w:ppr/w:pstyle/@w:val, 'Heading'))
>= number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/w:ppr/w:pstyle/@w:val, 'Heading'))
```

Here is the full XSLT, which is the identity transform, with the extra case to match such  **w:p** nodes and ignore thems:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p
   [
      preceding-sibling::w:p[1] 
      and 
         number(substring-after(w:ppr/w:pstyle/@w:val, 'Heading')) 
         >= number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/w:ppr/w:pstyle/@w:val, 'Heading'))   
   ]">
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input sample, the following output is generated:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:body>
      <w:p>
         <w:ppr>
            <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1"/>
         </w:ppr>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>Para1</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:ppr>
            <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1"/>
         </w:ppr>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>Para5</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:ppr>
            <w:pstyle w:val="Heading2"/>
         </w:ppr>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>Para8</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:ppr>
            <w:pstyle w:val="Heading1"/>
         </w:ppr>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>Para10</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: @@Tim: Thank you very much Tim...It's working absolutely fine.